# Relationship between copy(...) and copy(seq, ...)

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, copy, argument-dependent-lookup

**Is there a formal relationship between `std::copy` with and without an execution policy argument?** Either in practice or in the standard.

For example, would it be the case that simply,

```
namespace std{
    template<class It>
    It copy(std::execution::sequenced_policy, It first, It last, It d_first){
        return std::copy(first, last, d_first);
    }
}
```

or

```
namespace std{
    template<class It>
    It copy(std::execution::sequenced_policy, It first, It last, It d_first){
    //    using std::copy; // may not be needed
        return copy(first, last, d_first);
    }
}
```

Note that in the first version mean that I need to overload `copy(par::seq, ...)` as well.

or is the case that

```
namespace std{
    template<class It>
    It copy(std::execution::sequenced_policy, It first, It last, It d_first){
        ... not defined at all in terms of other `copy(It, ...)` or `std::copy(It, ...)`
    }
}
```

The reason is that I want to ADL overload the copy algorithm (in a custom namespace) for a special kind of iterator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One difference mentioned in [[execpol.seq]](http://eel.is/c++draft/execpol.seq#2) is

> During the execution of a parallel algorithm with the
>   `execution​::​sequenced_­policy` policy, if the invocation of an element
>   access function exits via an uncaught exception, `terminate()` shall be
>   called.

Demo:

```
#include <execution>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

struct C {
    C() {}
    C& operator=(const C&) {
        throw std::runtime_error("copy failed");
    }
};

int main() {
    C a[1];
    C b[1];

    try {
        std::copy(std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::begin(b));
    } catch(const std::runtime_error& ex) {
        std::cout << "Exception: " << ex.what() << "\n";
    }

    try {
        std::copy(std::execution::seq, std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::begin(b));
    } catch(const std::runtime_error& ex) {
        std::cout << "Exception: " << ex.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Possible output:

```
Exception: copy failed
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  copy failed
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Ok, that is a very useful detail to know. This also makes it less likely that one is implemented in terms of the other, but it is still possible (desirable?).

Comment: @alfC I think the standard allows for functions called with an `std::execution::sequenced_policy` to use a version of the function without an ExecutionPolicy, but it must `terminate()` if an exception is thrown. Possibly to allow for parallel algorithm implementations do things in parallel although element access is done in sequence, but that's just speculation on my behalf.

Comment: thanks. That makes sense. My ultimate question was whether I need to overload both copy and copy(seq for custom iterators. That also depends whether copy(seq is ADL friendly. Probably it is not standard, and I am on my own.

Comment: @alfC Oh, I've made plenty of custom iterators but I haven't made an overload for `copy`. When using a custom iterator with `copy(par` I noticed it did some strange stuff that I wasn't prepared for. If I remember correctly, the `par` implementation I tested it on looped over the range once before it started threads and then it actually did the work. It was tricky to create iterators for an unknown range where `it==end()` would depend on the result found by any of the threads if I remember correctly...

Comment: so, do you tend to overload everything that you need or you rely on implementing just the basics and rely in some structure? For example, par and seq, uninitialized_copy and copy. It is a lot of work 

Comment: I don't remember overloading any of the standard library functions :-) I hope they are good enough and just add iterators to whatever I'm doing. However, I got curious about the execution policies since it seems possible to implement more of them (like one where you can throw an exception that is somehow caught to exit a parallel `for_each` or similar) - but haven't found info about _how_. It may only be open for the compiler vendors to add more exec policies. :)

Comment: Now I remember more... I did this [brute force password cracker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55974224/7582247) and needed a way to terminate all threads in my `for_each(par...` nicely when the password was found. I ended up dropping `for_each(par...` and make an ugly variant with a thread pool myself. The password generator had an interesting iterator if I remember correctly :-) It has a link to code at godbolt at the bottom and the answer at SO explains what the code does.

Comment: It is unfortunate that one has to reinvent the well to implement parallel algorithms with error handling and break conditions. I think there must be a way of do it elegantly, perhaps even without allocations.